# Storing Limits As Two Variables

Tags: javascript

I've set a minimum of 60 for Strength in this tool, how can I set a maximum number?  When the tool is complete there will be more than just "Strength" so you know.

It was suggested that I store the limits as two variables, can anyone provide an example of this? I am new to JS.

[**CODE & DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: What does this question have to do with google? In fact, what _does_ this question have to do with? Very few people are going to click your link to read your code. You must post the _relevant_ code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the maximum and minimum as two properties of each statistic limit, as such:

```
Limits: {
    Strength: {
        max: 70,
        min: 60
    }
}
```

Then, do basically the same thing you are doing to check for the minimum, again for the maximum (in your `add` function).

```
if(newNumber > character.Limits[stat].max) return;
```

<kbd>[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/102/)</kbd>

Also, unrelated, but note that it is a Javascript naming conventions to have the object properties use lowercase names. In general, all variables except for globals and object constructors start with a lowercase letter.<sup>[See here](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names)</sup>

Comment: yes.. add commas ater the end }..

var Alexander = 
     {
      Strength: "AlexanderStrengthVal",
       Stamina: "AlexanderStaminaVal",
      Bonus: "AlexanderRemainingBonusVal",
      Limits: {
        Strength: { 
          max: 70,
          min: 60
        },
        Stamina: {
        max: 70,
        min: 60,
      },
              }
    };

Comment: You are missing a comma after the closing bracket of `Strength`

Comment: @Sunyatasattva I have a new question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409507/incorporating-onmouseup-down-functionality) that I wanted your opinion on.  All of your answers have been perfect for me thus far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First define your var

```
var maxStrength = 65.
```

Then define your condition in add funcion

```
function add(character, stat)
{

  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character["Bonus"]);
  if(parseInt(txtNumber.value) < maxStrength) {
    if(BonusVal.value == 0) return;
    var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 1;
    BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
    txtNumber.value = newNumber;
  }
}
```

In this way, it only adds new strength until reach the maximum,